# Binding from ObserverCollection to ToggleSwitch 'IsChecked'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I try to binding from observerCollection to ToggleSwitch(MahApp)
but it isnt work

XAML:

```
<mah:ToggleSwitch Name="switchLEDA" IsChecked="{Binding ConfParams[0], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<bool> ConfParams
    {
        get { return _chromaConfigurationModel.ConfParams; }
        set { _chromaConfigurationModel.ConfParams = value; }
    }
```

Model:

```
private ObservableCollection<bool> _confParams;
 public ObservableCollection<bool> ConfParams
    {
        get { return _confParams; }
        set { _confParams = value; }
    }
```

any one can halp me pls?

Comment: If you want an actual answer, you need to post a complete question, one that includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, as well as a better problem description than "it isnt [sic] work". However, based on the tiny bit of code you did share, it seems likely you aren't raising any `PropertyChanged` event when the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of a `bool` in an `ObservableCollection<bool>` so your `TwoWay` binding won't work. `bool` is a value type that is copied when it is passed around.

You should bind to a property that can actually be set:

```
public class ConfParams
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public ObservableCollection<ConfParams> ConfParams
{
    get { return _chromaConfigurationModel.ConfParams; }
    set { _chromaConfigurationModel.ConfParams = value; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<mah:ToggleSwitch Name="switchLEDA" IsChecked="{Binding ConfParams[0].Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
```